# Personal computer + employer's WiFi

Tags: privacy, wifi

I decided to use my personal Macbook at work, so I'll be using my employer's network connection. But I'm really concerned about my privacy. I know I can do non-work stuff using Tor Browser or Brave's Private window with Tor, but what about my reminders, notes, voice memos and other Apple's built in apps? I am really freaked about my personal stuff. How can I prevent them from accessing it? I know they may never do it, but if there is even the smallest risk, I want to prevent it somehow. Let's say I create another user account specifically for work without logging my Apple ID and use it, will it prevent them from accessing my data stored on another (personal) account?

Comment: You are worried about your employer doing bad things with your traffic, but willing to trust it to random people running Tor exit nodes?!

Answer (score 0):

Well, using some dedicated VPN service like NordVPN, or like you said, Tor, should really be enough. That is, unless your employer or co-employees are really nosy or you don't work while you're supposed to. Other things, such as built-in apps, usually remain confined to local storage unless you decide to sync them. Even so, unless you decide to sync to reminders, memos to your non-work Apple ID, not much can me done. And as for preventing them from accessing data stored on your personal account, just make sure you have a strong password.

TL;DR Nothing much to worry.